# ActiveCell.Row - I have a selection but it is giving me the last row of the activecell selection

Tags: vba, excel, selection, rows

I need the program to return the ActiveCell.Row number of the first row in a selection from the user in excel vba.

I have tried it but sometimes it is showing the last row of the active cell rather than the first.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Also is there a code to just show the range of the users selection? 
E.g. if they select range G3:G10, it would return G3:G10.

because I am now getting the first row of the users selection and then counting how many rows they have selected to work out the users selection that way.

Comment: *is there a code to just show the range of the users selection*... [`Selection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840834%28v=office.15%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 3):

`Range.Cells(1,1).Row` should return the row number of the first row in the range.

[`ActiveCell` is a range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673%28v=office.15%29.aspx), so you can substitute my range for activecell.